# Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql-server

```
<?php       
$serverName = "servername"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB", "UID"=>"user1", "PWD"=>"user@123");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes'  THEN city END) AS o_total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'No'  THEN city END) AS o_offline,
        COUNT(*) as t_total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes' AND channel='Name1' THEN city END) AS o_Name1, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name1' THEN city END) AS t_Name1, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'YES' AND channel='Name2' THEN city END) AS o_Name2, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name2' THEN city END) AS t_Name2, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes' AND channel='Name3' THEN city END) AS o_Name3, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name3' THEN city END) AS t_Name3, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes' AND channel='Name4' THEN city END) AS o_Name4, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name4' THEN city END) AS t_Name4, 
        city FROM wmm group by city";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $array = new stdClass();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $array->$row['city'] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($array);

        }

?>
```

I am having error=> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\User\File.php** on line **25**

Please help me to resolve this..thanks in advance

Comment: What if you use the `sqlsrv_query` function, passing both `$conn` and a simple test query right in your "Connection established" conditional block? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Answer (score 2):

`sqlsrv_connect()` doesn't return an object, but a resource.

You need to call `sqlsrv_query()` and pass the `$conn` resource as the first parameter and your query as the second.

All the PHP `sqlsrv` functions are documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php)

Answer (score 0):

try the connection this way:

```
<?php       
$dbservername= "servername"; 
$dbusername="user1";
$dbpassword="user@123";
$dbname="DB";
$conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error) {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( $conn->connect_error, true));
}
else{
     echo "Connection established.<br />";

      $sql = "SELECT 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes'  THEN city END) AS o_total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'No'  THEN city END) AS o_offline,
        COUNT(*) as t_total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes' AND channel='Name1' THEN city END) AS o_Name1, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name1' THEN city END) AS t_Name1, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'YES' AND channel='Name2' THEN city END) AS o_Name2, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name2' THEN city END) AS t_Name2, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes' AND channel='Name3' THEN city END) AS o_Name3, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name3' THEN city END) AS t_Name3, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN online = 'Yes' AND channel='Name4' THEN city END) AS o_Name4, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN channel='Name4' THEN city END) AS t_Name4, 
        city FROM wmm group by city";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $array = new stdClass();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $array->$row['city'] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($array);

        }
}


?>
```

Comment: Sorry but after correcting few things I m getting => mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\user\user1.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />